# Access a Cordova Plugin Variable in the Script of a Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I'm making a Cordova plugin and I'd like to be able to have a `--variable VARIABLE="someValue"` in the plugin installation.

I have an after_prepare script within my `plugin.xml`.

plugin.xml

`<preference name="VARIABLE" default="defaultValue" />`

`<hook src="script.js" type="after_prepare" />`

Usage of plugin would look like this:

`cordova plugin add pluginsource.git --fetch --variable VARIABLE="customvalue"`

Inside the script.js, how can I reference the value of that variable (so I see "customvalue") if the user chose to use that variable when installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable and arguments will be present in `process.argv` as the cordova cli is a nodejs tool.

```
 console.log(process.argv)
```

should provide you with an array of strings included in the `platform add` command use.

An example plugin which uses variables in after-prepare.js is the [cordova facebook plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I guess the follow up question is, what's the best way to save variables? Context here is, I see code like `
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/plugin.xml#L92 but I am trying to avoid wanting to save my variable in the Info.Plist or equivalent.

Comment: in the config.xml..I suppose

Comment: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/scripts/after_prepare.js#L22