# Cordova plugin variables

Tags: cordova, plugins, cordova-ios, cordova-android

How can I use variables in the Swift/Kotlin code of my Cordova plugin, for iOS and Android?

I mean the variables that were defined in config.xml, and now live in package.json, that looked like this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.0">
    <variable name="MY_VARIABLE" value="my_variable_value" />
</plugin>
```

... I know how to set these when installing my custom plugin, but I don't see any mention in the documentation about how to access them within the plugin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a Cordova Plugin Variable in the Script of a Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833386/access-a-cordova-plugin-variable-in-the-script-of-a-plugin)

Comment: No, thanks @Eric; I was interested in access from the backend code, so I clarified that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not accesible from code, variables are just a way of changing a value in the plugin.xml, can be used to make a SDK version configurable, or to write the value to the Info.plist or AndroidManifest.xml or strings.xml or other native files, then you can read those files from the native code as you would do on iOS/Android.

In example to read from `Info.plist` you would do it like this:

```
NSString *myValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"MyValue"]];
```

To write in the Info.plist

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="MyValue">
   <string>$MY_VARIABLE</string>
</config-file>
```

To read from `strings.xml`

```
Activity activity = cordova.getActivity();
    String packageName = activity.getPackageName();
    int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(“MyValue”, "string", packageName);
String myValue = activity.getString(resId);
```

To write to `strings.xml`

```
<config-file target="./res/values/strings.xml" parent="/resources">
    <string name="MyValue">$MY_VARIABLE</string>
</config-file>
```

Comment: Thanks, and I found this other answer which seems a little more direct; using a preference and getting the value from the settings dictionary, but it doesn't seem to be in there... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559164/2199492

Comment: preferences are a different thing, you put them in the config.xml directly instead of passing them in the plugin add command and you can read them from code in an easier way, but I don't think you can mix a preference and a variable.
You can try something like this
```<config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
    <preference name="MyValue" value="$MY_VARIABLE"/>
</config-file>```, but not sure if it will actually get replaced

Comment: A preference tag in config.xml is available in the settings dict, but not one in plugin.xml.

Comment: Yeah, you can't put the preference tag directly in `plugin.xml`, but you can put the `config-file` tag  like the one I put on my previous comment, that would write it in the resulting `config.xml`, but I'm not sure if the variable will be replaced with the actual value.